# if statement can't re-enable a disabled field

Tags: javascript

I am having issues re-enabling a field after it being disabled

```js
function disableDate() {
  if (document.getElementById("ongoing").checked = true) {
    document.getElementById("findate").disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("findate").disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="ongoing" type="checkbox" name="educations'[ongoing]" onclick="disableDate()">

<input id="findate" type="text" name="educations[finish_date]" data-date-start-date="0" data-date-autoclose="true" data provide="datepicker" placeholder="Finish Date" />
```

Comment: Your condition is an [assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment) `=` use a [comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) `===`.

Comment: Which kind of "issues" do you have? Can you explain what exactly is not working, and what you've tried to resolve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

= is for assignment and === is for compare

```
function disableDate() {
        if(document.getElementById("ongoing").checked){
            document.getElementById("findate").disabled = true;
        }
    else{
        document.getElementById("findate").disabled = false;
    }
}
```